# Glassfish RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool. Exception : null

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jsf, jdbc, glassfish

I am using GlassFish 3.1.1, SQL Server 2008, and NetBeans with Hibernate 3 and JSF 2.0 to create a web application. I am able to retrieve data with the hibernate API successfully but for some reason, the connection pool becomes null when I try to click a commandButton that takes me from one page to another page. In the action method, I am simply making a call to getOriginCount() but the hibernate API is giving a weird null error. Not sure if it's glassfish pool, hibernate, or sql server.

```
WARNING: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ perfpro-jdbc-pool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
WARNING: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null]
SEVERE: 1237767 [http-thread-pool-8080(2)] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null

SEVERE: 1237772 [http-thread-pool-8080(2)] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null

WARNING: /cloneBuilderMenu.xhtml @31,168 rendered="#{cloneBuilderBean.canCreateMoreClones}": org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
javax.el.ELException: /cloneBuilderMenu.xhtml @31,168 rendered="#{cloneBuilderBean.canCreateMoreClones}": org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:413)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:933)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:344)
    at $Proxy146.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.perpro.controller.dao.impl.AssessmentDaoImpl.getOriginCount(AssessmentDaoImpl.java:145)
    at com.perpro.controller.cloneBuilderBean.getCanCreateMoreClones(cloneBuilderBean.java:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:160)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:113)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.resizePoolAndGetNewResource(ConnectionPool.java:792)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResourceFromPool(ConnectionPool.java:760)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getUnenlistedResource(ConnectionPool.java:632)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:526)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:242)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:167)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:301)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.FailoverMapSingleton.getFailoverInfo(FailOverMapSingleton.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:685)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:593)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:57)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 80 more

WARNING: RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool perfpro-jdbc-pool. Exception : null
WARNING: RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool perfpro-jdbc-pool. Exception : null
WARNING: RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool perfpro-jdbc-pool. Exception : null
WARNING: RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool perfpro-jdbc-pool. Exception : null
WARNING: RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool perfpro-jdbc-pool. Exception : null
WARNING: RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool perfpro-jdbc-pool. Exception : null
WARNING: RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool perfpro-jdbc-pool. Exception : null
```

Here is the method where the nullpointer happens at session.beginTransaction(); The HibernateUtil class is generated by Netbeans.

```
public Integer getOriginCount() throws Exception {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Integer originCount = ((Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from origin").uniqueResult()).intValue();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return originCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The NPE seem to originate from a `SQLServerDataSource.getConnection` call. It is possible that either your datasource or database is incorrectly configured. To start with, I will try disabling failover clustering.